# Why is the movie titled "The White Balloon"?

Tags: title, the-white-balloon

If anyone has seen [The White Balloon](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112445/) by Jafar Panahi, could you please share your view why the title of the film is that?

Comment: First of all, a white balloon seems to be a prominent part of the plot. But as to the deeper meaning of that balloon (which isn't asked, though) or why that in particular was chosen for the title I have no idea (not having seen the movie at all).

Comment: I haven't seen it, but perhaps someone who has can answer: is there a reference to the classic [The Red Balloon](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0048980/)?

Answer (score 1):

Reading the [Wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_White_Balloon), it says the following:

> Finally, the siblings receive help from a young Afghan street vendor selling balloons. He carries all of his balloons on a wooden stick, and has only one balloon, a white one, left. The group attaches a piece of gum to one end of the balloon stick, and with it, they reach down through the grate and pull the money out.

The white balloon is an object which is quintessential to the story line. I do not believe there is anything more to it than that.

You can find out more about the [film at AllMovie](http://www.allmovie.com/movie/v134796) or at the [Wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_White_Balloon).

Comment: Meh, that (the summary mentioning the balloon) I could gather from the Wiki page, too, but didn't find it worth an answer. And the second part of the answer doesn't seem to contribute much. I guess the OP has seen the movie. But ok, if he hasn't (which would make the question a bit strange in the first place), this answer might even be sufficient for him.

Comment: Really? A down vote for answering the question? Isn't that special.

Comment: I haven't downvoted it (but maybe somebody else agreed with me and took the issue more serious, which isn't so special at all ;-)).

Comment: @ChristianRau ... I know you didn't down vote. The problem here is, along with many other comments you've made, you believe there must be some deep dark secret involved within the movie which isn't so obvious. Sometimes, a white balloon is just that ... a white balloon. Why does it have to be a complicated answer when it is nothing but simple.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a complicated answer and there doesn't necessarily need to be any more to it than, well, a white balloon. But I just assumed that the OP has seen a movie about whose title he asks and if that is the case, he probably wants to hear something more than *"it was part of the movie"*. If there isn't more to it, then be it so. And for the single possibility he hasn't seen the movie or it is really just a darn white balloon, the answer still makes sense, which is the case I'd deem it valid. You could at least say that you don't think there to be more to it than that.

Comment: What is wrong in expecting a deep dark secret everywhere? I *don't* regard answers as worthless that don't reveal one anyway (but I don't have to up-vote them either). ;-)

Comment: I don't think that the question is expecting a secret,per say, but usually even an important "object" featured in a film or a novel can be seen as symbolic  and symbols are often metaphors for something. I haven't seen the film or know if white balloons relate at all to Iranian culture, but I suspect that it could be about expectations and coming of age, as balloons are generally about celebrations/milestones in life and/or are often things associated with childhood